# Using a variable in XAML binding expression

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm building a control that can edit POCOs. There is a descriptor collection for the fields within the POCO that need to be edited and I'm binding a `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` to this collection. Amongst other things, the descriptor gives me the ability to select a suitable `DataTemplate` and the variable name in the POCO that this `ListBox` item should edit.

My ListBox is built like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnCollection, ElementName=root}">
    <ListBox.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                <!-- !!! Question about following line !!! -->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=vm.CurentEditing, Path=PathName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Details omitted for brevity -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PickListTemplate" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate" />
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:DataTypeSelector
            TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"
            PickListTemplate="{StaticResource PickListTemplate}"
            BooleanTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanTemplate}"
            />
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>

</ListBox>
```

It is the `TextBox` binding expression in the "TextTemplate" that I am having problems with. The problem is that "PathName" should not be taken as a literal string, but is the name of a string property in the `ColumnDescription` class (the collection type of `ColumnCollection` used for `ListBox.ItemsSource`), which gives the name of the POCO property I want to bind to (the POCO is "vm.CurrentEditing").

Is there some way to use the value of a property in XAML as input to a binding expression, or will I have to resort to code behind?

(Incidentally, specifying the `ElementName` as "x.y" as I have done above also seems to be invalid. I assume the "y" part should be in `Path` but that's currently taken up with my property name...!)

Comment: `ElementName` is just the name, everything else goes in the `Path`, using `.` to access sub-properties.

Comment: Do you want to do something analogous to ListBox.DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: @H.B. I thought that must be the case (and probably knew it at some point in the past). Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I suppose I am, in the case where `DisplayMemberPath` is itself bound to a property. No doubt that's implemented in code behind.

Comment: Yes, the way I've done stuff like that is to create a `Binding` programmatically with the arbitrary string for its Path property (there may likely be a better/more canonical way, but that has worked for me). Maybe you'd want to do it with an attached property or something; unfortunately what you're doing is one level of abstraction beyond what my poor brain can contend with right after lunch.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks. Feel free to knock up a couple lines to that effect in an answer and (assuming no one else comes along with some fantastic method neither of us knows about) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to bind `TextBox.Text` to Property X of Object Y, where X and Y both change at runtime.

It sounds like what you want to do is something analogous to `ListBox.DisplayMemberPath`: You can bind a `string` or `PropertyPath` property to `DisplayMemberPath` and it'll work. The way I've done stuff like that is to have a dependency property of type `String` or `PropertyPath`, and programatically create a binding from that to whatever property.

So, I wrote an attached property which creates a binding.

```cs
public class POCOWrangler
{
    #region POCOWrangler.BindPropertyToText Attached Property
    public static String GetBindPropertyToText(TextBox obj)
    {
        return (String)obj.GetValue(BindPropertyToTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindPropertyToText(TextBox obj, PropertyPath value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindPropertyToTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindPropertyToTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindPropertyToText", typeof(String), typeof(POCOWrangler),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, BindPropertyToText_PropertyChanged));

    private static void BindPropertyToText_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is String && d is TextBox)
        {
            var tb = d as TextBox;
            var binding = new Binding((String)e.NewValue);

            //  The POCO object we're editing must be the DataContext of the TextBox, 
            //  which is what you've got already -- but don't set Source explicitly 
            //  here. Leave it alone and Binding.Source will be updated as 
            //  TextBox.DataContext changes. If you set it explicitly here, it's 
            //  carved in stone. That's especially a problem if this attached 
            //  property gets initialized before DataContext.
            //binding.Source = tb.DataContext;

            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(tb, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
        }
    }
    #endregion POCOWrangler.BindPropertyToText Attached Property
}
```

And I wrote a quick example thing: There's a little class named `Foo` that has a `Name` property, and a viewmodel with two properties, `Foo Foo` and `String DisplayPathName`. It works! Of course, this depends on default `TextBox` editing behavior for whatever type the property happens to be. I think that will get you the same results as if you'd bound explicitly in XAML, but it sitll won't always necessarily be just what you want. But you could very easily go a little nuts and add some triggers in the `DataTemplate` to swap in different editors, or write a `DataTemplateSelector`.

I stuffed `ViewModel.Foo` in a `ContentControl` just to get a `DataTemplate` into the act, so that the `TextBox` gets his `DataContext` in the same manner as yours.

Note also that I'm getting `DisplayPathName` by a *relative source* from something outside the `DataContext` object -- it's not a member of `Foo`, of course, it's a member of the viewmodel.

C#

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new ViewModel { 
            DisplayPathName = "Name",
            Foo = new Foo { Name = "Aloysius" }
        };
}
```

XAML

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding Foo}"
    >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox
                local:POCOWrangler.BindPropertyToText="{Binding 
                    DataContext.DisplayPathName, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

That was fun.

Comment: Above and beyond! Here I am asking whether a quick XAML trick was possible and I get a thorough, eminently reusable coded solution! Thanks so much.

Comment: @BobSammers You're welcone.