# WPF: Binding inside resources section - can't access DatatContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having a binding problem inside the resources section of a `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<Window
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
    ...
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <!-- Binding below doesn't seem to work -->
                    <local:FreezableProxyElement x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
                    <local:Message x:Key="Message" Text="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" />
                </DataTemplate.Resources>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label>Text</Label>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource Message}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label>Integer</Label>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.Resources>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <local:DataTypeSelector
                TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"
                IntegerTemplate="{StaticResource IntegerTemplate}"
                />
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>

    </ItemsControl>
```

Apologies for the length (and the contrived example) - I've tried to be as brief as possible. The important part is the `Resources` section of the first `DataTemplate` ("TextTemplate").

Supporting code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>() { (int)5, "Hello World!" };
}

public class Message : DependencyObject
{
    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Message));
}

public class FreezableProxyElement : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        => new FreezableProxyElement();

    public object Data
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(DataProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(FreezableProxyElement));
}

public class DataTypeSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TextTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate IntegerTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case string s:
                return TextTemplate;
            case int i:
                return IntegerTemplate;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've always understood that in a resources section, a `Freezable`-derived object could inherit the `DataContext` from its container (which, in this `DataTemplate`, should be an item from `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` and this is verified by the collection's integer "5" being correctly displayed by "IntegerTemplate"). However, the text string is not displayed and the binding to "FreezeableProxyElement.Data" in the "TextTemplate" resources section yields a data error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'FreezableProxyElement' (HashCode=12379565); target property is 'Data' (type 'Object')
```

This is the error I would expect to see if `FreezableProxyElement` *wasn't* derived from `Freezable`. What's the problem here, and is there a good way around it?

Comment: Why does the Message class exist? I know what it's doing, I read the code. I'm asking *why did you add a class that does that*?

Comment: So I could have something that used the Proxy class! In my real code there's a more useful (complicated) class there that isn't germane to this problem.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's a possibility I'm aware of, but the general problem I've described could be applicable in many real scenarios, whether or not my particular issue could be solved in a better way. Having said that, what I'm actually trying to do is based on an answer [you yourself gave me a few months back!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082175/using-a-variable-in-xaml-binding-expression)

Comment: Oh great, that means there's no way for me to weasel out of this one.

Comment: Any comment from the downvoter?

Comment: There generally isn't. At a guess, somebody thought what you were doing could and should be done in some much easier way. But one downvote could be anything. When it's obviously a bad question or answer, you get two or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt a disturbance in the Framework that led me to suspect that the `DataTemplate`'s resources were at one too many removes from reality. I don't know exactly what the problem was (visual tree, logical tree, something or other), but I was able to reproduce it, and the following works for me:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:FreezableProxyElement 
                x:Key="Proxy" 
                Data="{Binding}" 
                />
            <local:Message 
                x:Key="Message" 
                Text="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" 
                />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Label>Text</Label>
        <Label 
            Content="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource Message}}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I still suspect that this is an XY Problem, and that the real solution is to create `Message` some other way. But without knowing more details I can't give you that answer.

### Update

How to do a binding trace:

```
Text="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource Proxy}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

Don't leave those all over the place, they eat cycles.

Comment: Perhaps you're right with the XY thing. Moving the Resources section from the DataTemplate to the StackPanel *does* solve the data error 2 I reported, but in my more complicated code *creates* a set of Data error 40s in a manner that is no more explicable (to me at least, although perhaps they were being masked by the first error previously). I'll have to do some more digging around, I think.

Comment: Is that just "property not found on object"? That shouldn't be tough to resolve.

Comment: @BobSammers See my update about tracing a binding. You get lots of detail in the Output pane in VS. Should help identify exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: "Message" in the example code is actually a set of values for a BindingIndirector class that provides an attached property in the manner of the POCOWrangler class you suggested to me in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082175/using-a-variable-in-xaml-binding-expression) I referenced above.

Comment: Oh, wow. But it just sounds like one of the bindings on one of these things is binding to something that's not there. Just keep sticking `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` on bindings until you find out what.

Comment: That binding trace technique looks handy - thanks! The "40" errors might just be because there isn't anything on the other end of the binding when the program first runs. I've still got some *other* 2s to worry about as well. This all worked fine before a "harmless" refactoring...

Comment: LOL, we need a [tag:harmless-refactoring] tag.

Comment: ;) for the tag suggestion - might be quite a popular one! It's all working now - thank you. Moving the resources down a level was the key so points for that, and the TraceLevel setting was also useful and something I didn't know about. Ironically, I moved the resources section in the opposite direction before posting this question because I got fewer binding errors, but it turns out the multiple ones I *was* getting with it further down were ultimately easier to fix. (What I was missing, incidentally, was a further freezable proxy for ElementName refs to outside the DataTemplate.)